# построить санки плот в R

Tags: r

Первый файл (Название s):

[image]

Второй файл (Название w):

[image]

Вот код

```
library(networkD3)
df_nodes <- s
df_links <- w
a <- sankeyNetwork(Links = df_links, Nodes = df_nodes, Source = "source",
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   fontSize = 10, nodeWidth = 15)
a
```

Код машиной принимается, но рисунок не выходит. Подскажите, в чем проблема? может перепутаны аргументы в функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Перепутаны `df_nodes` и `df_links`.
2. Не все узлы указаны в `df_nodes`.

Если все это исправить, то получается вот такой код:

```
library(networkD3)
df_nodes <- data.frame(name = 0:5)
df_links <- data.frame(source = rep(0:4, each = 5),
                target = rep(1:5, 5),
                value = c(324, 308, 45, 9, 9, 434, 1489, 402, 91, 23, 64, 420, 344, 84, 26, 16, 102, 88, 66, 30, 0, 11, 25, 12, 26))
sankeyNetwork(Links = df_links, Nodes = df_nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 10, nodeWidth = 15)
```

Который рисует вот такой график. Вид графика показывает, что, видимо, была сделана еще и третья ошибка: что-то напутано на уровне приписывания индексов `sorce` и `target`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подскажите @aGricolaMZ, как  приписать индексы sorce и target для данных, которые распределены следующим образом (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO20u.png)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что есть что в Вашей табличке. Может быть нарисуете результат на бумаге? Или еще лучше, посмотрите на минимальный пример вот здесь: https://agricolamz.github.io/DS_for_DH/viz-1.html#визуализация-комбинаций-признаков (только помните, что в этом учебнике все сделано на tidyverse)?

Answer (score 0):

Представляю решение с помощью  пакета ggforce.
Как должны выглядеть исходные данные, показано на рисунке:

[image: Исходные данные представлены на рисунке]

Код  самих санки плот

```
library("ggforce")
  w %>% 
  gather_set_data(1:2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value), col=red)+
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = `доверяете коллегам`), alpha = 0.4, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.2,fill = "grey") +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(angle = 0)+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]